# If I use a simple substitution algorithm on a unique string, will the output be always unique?

Tags: algorithm, hash

This is sort of like hashing, but simpler. Something like:

```
function getUniqueId(input) {
    var map = {
            A: 'Q', B: 'W', C: 'E',
            D: 'R', E: 'T', F: 'Y',
            G: 'U', H: 'I', I: 'O',
            J: 'P', K: 'A', L: 'S',
            M: 'D', N: 'F', O: 'G',
            P: 'H', Q: 'J', R: 'K',
            S: 'L', T: 'Z', U: 'X',
            V: 'C', W: 'V', X: 'B',
            Y: 'N', Z: 'M',
            a: 'q', b: 'w', c: 'e',
            d: 'r', e: 't', f: 'y',
            g: 'u', h: 'i', i: 'o',
            j: 'p', k: 'a', l: 's',
            m: 'd', n: 'f', o: 'g',
            p: 'h', q: 'j', r: 'k',
            s: 'l', t: 'z', u: 'x',
            v: 'c', w: 'v', x: 'b',
            y: 'n', z: 'm',
            0: '3', 1: '4', 2: '5',
            3: '6', 4: '7', 5: '8',
            6: '9', 7: '0', 8: '1',
            9: '2',
        },
        output = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (map[input[i]] !== undefined){
            output += map[input[i]];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

I only encode/hash/substitute A-Z, a-z, and 0-9.

Provided that the input string is always unique, will the output string be **always unique** as well?

Comment: How does the substitution function work? `e` in `Hey` becomes `s`, but `e`'s in `there` become `x` ?

Comment: That was mistake on my part. Thank you, it should be x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hash gets created by applying the same substitution function on every character of a string which is unique, you can be sure that the output string will always be unique only if the substitution function is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).
This property preservers distinctness, which is what is needed to prevent uniqueness.

To check this property, this needs to be proved: `a ≠ b, then f(a) ≠ f(b)`. For your map - for numbers its obvious, for letters it might be confusing, but can be checked with a simple bash script, which collects all target values to see if none is present twice:

```
echo "A: Q, B: W, C: E, D: R, E: T, F: Y, G: U, H: I, I: O, J: P,  G, P: H, Q: J, R: K, S: L, T: Z, U: X, V: C, W: V, X: B, Y: N, Z: M" | tr ',' '\n' | cut -d':' -f2 | sort | tr -d ' \n'
```

Which indeed outputs

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Because your function doesn't change positions of characters and every character is subjected to this one-to-one mapping, unique input will always produce a unique output.

This is of course only true if you are certain that the input string is in the domain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, otherwise it won't work (`"@A"=>"Q"`,`"A"=>"Q"`).

Comment: I made a mistake before, the first e should be x. Thanks though, I got the answer, its going to be unique.

Comment: I added the algorithm.

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee I edited the answer to take your edits into account, the approach of the proof should be already straight forward

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on how you define "simple substitution".

If you strictly apply "substitute `a` with `emen`" (and nothing else), the result of applying this substitution (which I would call "simple", but not "reversible") to the strings "cat" and "cement" both end up with the reult "cement".

*EDIT*: You only have single-letter substitutions, so "all" you need to ensure is that there's no "destination character" that is mapped to by two (or more) "source characters".

The easiest way of doing this is probably to generate a string that contains all the possible mappable characters (so, the alphabet in uppercase and lowercase, and all the numbers) in whatever sorting order you prefer (sorting by ASCII value is probably easiest). Then you generate the encoded version, sort that and compare them.

Since you're mapping all the source characters, and you have a string composed only of the destination characters, if their sorted versions are identical, you do not have any duplication and thus you can guarantee that two distinct strings also have distinct encoded forms.

Comment: Hey, I added my substitution function. Can you check it out?

Comment: In principle, yes. However, I prefer editing my answer to show how you can do it yourself.